# Facebook ads 1634011 error: "Invalid property selector given action types"

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

I keep getting this error when I try to create an ad (adgroup) using the [facebook ads python sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sd). Here is the setup I have and the result I want to achieve:

- i already have a campaign (campaign group)
- i already have an adset
- the bid type I want to have is CPA
- i'm able to create the creative bound to the unpublished post
- **BUT** when i want to create the adgroup bound to the creative, i receive the error: *Invalid property selector given action types. The property selectors don't map to any known objects based on the action type(s) in the spec.*

I first thought that something wasn't created in the right way (for instance the post didn't exist). But I tripled checked with no success...

Here is the whole backtrace from the python client:

```
FacebookRequestError: Call was not successful 
Request:
    {'files': {}, 'path': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_xxxxxxx/adgroups', 'params': {'name': 'SDK ad name', 'adgroup_status': 'ACTIVE', 'objective': 'WEBSITE_CLICKS', 'creative': '{"creative_id":"xxxxxxx"}', 'conversion_specs': '[{"action.type":"link_click","post.wall":xxxxxxxx,"post_id":"xxxxxxx"}]', 'campaign_id': u'xxxxxxxx'}, 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'fb-python-ads-api-sdk-2.2.5'}}
Response:
    HTTP Status: 500
    Headers:{'content-length': '307', 'facebook-api-version': 'v2.2', 'expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'x-fb-debug': 'xxxxxxx', 'x-fb-rev': '1604454', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-store', 'date': 'Thu, 19 Feb 2015 01:16:54 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'www-authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Invalid parameter"'}
    Body: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_subcode":1634011,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Invalid property selector given action types","error_user_msg":"The property selectors don't map to any known objects based on the action type(s) in the spec."}}
```

Im' a bit stuck here, does anyone have a clue?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conversion specs are incorrect

You have

```
[{"action.type":"link_click","post.wall":xxxxxxxx,"post_id":"xxxxxxx"}]
```

For to select a page post, it should be:

```
[{"action.type":"link_click","post.wall":xxxxxxxx,"post":"xxxxxxx"}]
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/action-specs/v2.2 has examples you can follow

Comment: I tried with that too and didn't work at the time. I'll try again to see if I did make a mistake, thanks

Comment: i still get the same kind of error (not exactly the same though):
`Body: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_subcode":1634019,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"The id of the object (post, page, etc) passed in is invalid.","error_user_msg":"Please check that a valid and non-empty object id is passed in."}}`

I doubled check, both the post and the page are valid

Comment: I've modify the structure of my call to:
`{"action.type": ["link_click"], "post": "pageid_postid", "post.wall": pageid}` but I get the same error... any idea?

Comment: The other exception implies the format is correct but the values are wrong - where are you getting the value you're using in"pageid_postid"? Are you manually crafting that string somehow, or taking it verbatim  from the `id` field of a page post on a Facebook Page's `/promotable_posts` endpoint? if the latter, this should be working as far as I can see

Comment: I'm creating a hidden post during the creative creation (object_spec) and use the ids as is. When I try to access the post it displays correctly in FB. Am I missing sthg?

Comment: Without knowing the exact IDs involved it's hard to be sure, but the implication is that you can't see the post, can't see the page, don't have advertiser permission on the page, are using a page other than the one the post is on, the post is from a user rather than a page, something like that

Comment: I just tried to create the hidden post with the creative before creating the adgroup. I still get the error. The hidden post id is `507290532633244_999079466787679` and I checked in the graph explorer, the post is in the `promotable_post` route. Is it possible that some kind of race condition occurs? Plus, regarding the rights, it worked completely fine with a CPC bidding time (keeping the hidden post), so I don't see why it is not working...